# Save ArrayList Between activity transtion

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

Im having a lot of trouble here.

**Problem:** I have two activities A and B. In activity A i have a listview with custom items. I have all data of these items storage in an ArrayList. When the user clicks on a listview item, the activity B is called displaying details about that item. When the user comes back to activity A, all items that were inside listiview are **gone**. I know that i need to save listview state, so i need to save the data of the arraylist.

**Question:** How to solve this problem?

**Notes:** i have tryed onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState, but since transition between these two activities A and B are fast, the activity A is not destroyed. So i cannot save my ArrayList in a bundle object.
I have also tryed to use SharedPrefereces and ContentValues but nor of these classes have support for Parcelable objects and for Lists.

**Thanks for your help!**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstView);

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (ni != null && ni.isConnected())
        updateListView();
    registerClickCallback();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    listResorces = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(LIST_RESOURCES);
    ArrayAdapter<Record> adapter = new BandejaoItemAdapter(listResorces);
    lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(LIST_RESOURCES, listResorces);
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you are doing some reset inside `onResume()`. Can you please post relevant code?

Comment: Yes i can! I'll edit my question... in a sec **i have no override methods onResume and onPause()**

Comment: That is all of the `Activity`?

Comment: No, thats not all.. thats just the important code that handles with activity transition.
I believe i have found the solution for the problem. The problem is the up button from the action bar that instead of do the same as the back button, it destroy your previous activity and then recreate it. The solution for this, i beliave is a property in the manifest file for the parent activity

**android:launchMode="singleTop"**

i have implemented SharedPreferences too in a "hack" way, but i dont think its a good idea doing this. For now, its working...